# Kohana3 - Error Template if errors = FALSE

Tags: model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-3, php

In my Bootstrap.php I've deactivated the Profiler (or is it better to be activated?), and the Errors.

Now if somebody is calling an Url, maybe: /notexist, and there is no action_notexist(), the Site is blank.

My Question: How can I create a main Error Template, which should be loaded instead of the white page. E.g. If you call: http://twitter.com/notexistinguser, there is a "Page does not exist" Error, the same with Kohana3?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't ignore exceptions, catch them.

Comment: For an example of catching exceptions see http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=routing:404_pages_by_catching_reflection_exception

Comment: nice @slacker =) Looks interesting.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is catch the *Kohana_Exception* in your *bootstrap.php* file. Here's a code sample from one of my projects.

```
try
{
    echo Request::instance()
        ->execute()
        ->send_headers()
        ->response;
}
catch (Kohana_Exception $e)
{
    echo Request::factory('static/404')->execute()->send_headers()->response;
}
```

I'll explain what's going on here.  If a route doesn't exist for the URL requested then it throws a *Request_Exception*  (instance of Kohana_Exception).

I then use the HMVC feature to create a sub-request to the 404 page which deals with the template, status codes, logging and error messages.

In the future Kohana might have a special exception which deals with responses, but for now you can use my solution.

Hope that helped you out.

Comment: an interesting way, I will try it... This are the end lines of the bootstrap? Am I right? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Kohana but I use the following technique.
First, define some constant, for example IN_PRODUCTION:

```
define('IN_PRODUCTION', true);
```

Second, create new Exception class, for example **Exception_404** that inherits **Kohana_Exception**.
Third, replace this code:

```
echo Request::instance()
->execute()
->send_headers()
->response;
```

with following:

```
$request = Request::instance();
try 
{
    $request->execute();
}
catch(Exception_404 $e)
{
    if ( ! IN_PRODUCTION)
    {
        throw $e;
    }

    //404 Not Found
    $request->status = 404;
    $request->response = View::factory('404');
}

print $request->send_headers()->response;
```

Now you have your own error template. Is that what you want?

Comment: There's no need to create IN_PRODUCTION as Kohana has a Kohana::$environment variable. This can be coupled with the constants Kohana::PRODUCTION, Kohana::STAGING & Kohana::DEVELOPMENT